# What's a good way to look up list of enumerated values?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection of `case` with a field named `status` (integer) whose valid values are 0, 1, 2, 4 and 8, representing "New", "WIP", "Solved", "Canceled" and "Closed" respectively.

So, in mongoose syntax, it might be like:

```
const caseSchema = new Schema({
  createdOn: Date,
  subittedBy: String,
  status: Number,
  ...
});

const statusSchema = new Schema({
  value: Number,
  description: String
});
```

Is this a good way to organize the data? How do I make a query to retrieve cases with the `status` field properly filled with the `description`?

Answer (score 0):

It is one way to do it sure. You could do the query by using [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). It would look something like this:

```
db.getCollection('<YourCasesColName>').aggregate([
    { $match : { 'status' : 1 } }, // or { $in: [1,2,3] },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: '<YourStatusColName>',
        localField: 'status',
        foreignField: 'value',
        as: 'statusDoc',
      }
    }
 ])
```

Another way is to add a [reference to the actual status](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) via ObjectId so that instead of numbers in the cases you would be storing references to the actual Status objects and in this way have a better referential integrity. However you would still need to do similar query to get both in one shot. So here is what I am talking about:

```
const caseSchema = new Schema({
  createdOn: Date,
  subittedBy: String,
  status: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Status' },
  // ^ now your status hows reference to exactly the type of status it has
});

const statusSchema = new Schema({
  value: Number,
  description: String
});

So the actual data would look like this:

// Statuses
[{
  _id: <StatusMongoObjectID_1>,
  value: 1,
  description: 'New'
},{
  _id: <StatusMongoObjectID_2>,
  value: 2,
  description: 'New'
}]

// Cases
[{
  _id: <MongoObjectID>,
  createdOn: '<SomeISODate>',
  subittedBy: '<SomeString>',
  status: <StatusMongoObjectID_1>
},
{
  _id: <MongoObjectID>,
  createdOn: '<SomeISODate>',
  subittedBy: '<SomeString>',
  status: <StatusMongoObjectID_2>
}]
```